# Curve length under Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

On [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80508/volume-change-under-linear-transformation) mathoverflow post, we can see that from $T : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ linear tranformation with matrix $A$ and a measurable set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, we have:

$$ \mu(T(S)) = |\det(A)|\mu(S) $$

Is there a way to generalize this notion for the length of a curve in, say, $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$. That is, is there an way to relate the arclength of an curve under linear transformation to it's original arclength?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the length of a curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is given by $$l(\gamma)=\int_a^b\|\dot{\gamma}(t)\|dt.$$ Given a linear $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, we compose and get $$l(T\circ\gamma)=\int_a^b\|T(\dot{\gamma}(t))\|dt.$$ I don't think one can hope for something much better in general. For example, the ellipse can be obtained by a very simple linear transformation of the circle, yet the perimeter of the latter is *much* easier to calculate than that of the former.

Comment: We can get the inequality $l(T\circ\gamma)\leq\|T\|\,l(\gamma)$

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that with volume we have $\text{vol}(Tx_1,\dots,Tx_n)=|\det A|\,\text{vol}(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ for parallelepipeds formed by $n$ vectors, by multiplicativity of determinants. But with length $l(Tx)$ is not any characteristic of $T$ times $l(x)$. The best we can have is the inequality $l(Tx)\leq\|T\|\,l(x)$. Both the equality and the inequality translate into ones for set measures and curve lengths respectively under integration.